# if there is already an 'onchange' event on a dropdown, if I bind another, when will it fire?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is an 'onchange' event, using inline javascript on a dropdown list which I have no control over.

In the onready event, if I bind another onchange event, which one will fire first?  And will this be a gauranteed order?

I want mine to fire AFTER the inline js onchange event.

Comment: why don't you simply try this yourself by putting different `alert()`-messages into both functions and see what happens (in different browsers)?

Comment: @oezi observation is not a good method to determine if something is guaranteed to work.

Comment: The way to guarantee order is to have the first method call the second.

Comment: @oezi it could be browser dependant, etc etc.

Answer (score 2):

In most implementations, events fire in the order that they are specified. This order is not guaranteed, though. The ECMAScript spec does not define this.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you can replace the initial `onchange` methdod.

```
var select = document.getElementById('myElementId');
var proxy = select.onchange;
select.onchange=null;
var wrapper = function (e) {
  if (!window.event) { 
   // for compatibility on non-IE browsers where event may be used inline
   // untested
   window.event = e; 
  }
  // executes the original handler in the scope of the original element
  proxy.apply(select); 
  // new function you want to run
  myFn();
};
if (select.addEventListener) {
  select.addEventListener('change', wrapper ,false);
}
else {
  select.attachEvent('onchange', wrapper);
}
```

I have this working as a proof of concept. What does the original element markup look like? Depending on what variables are referenced in the original `onchange` it may or may not fit your problem.

live demo: http://jsbin.com/ufohu4